# Refer to a numbered column without using volatile functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use `COUNTIF` to count the number of cells in a column that contain a given string. The column to be checked is specified by a cell that contains a number.

Here is a simplified version of what I have at the moment.

[image]

The number 3 in cell G1 indicates that the column to be searched is the 3rd column to the right of the "Name" column, the one headed "R3" (Row D). The formula in cell G2 correctly counts the number of cells in column D that contain "Y".

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A:A,0,G1),"Y")
```

The problem with this formula is that the `OFFSET` function is [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation) which means that any time I open the workbook, the formula is recalculated. If I try to close the workbook without making any changes, I get the dialog box asking if I want to save my (nonexistent) changes.

Is there an alternative formula that will calculate the number of "Y"s in a column without using a volatile function?
 If it helps, the real column headers for the columns I am interested in are indeed R1, R2, R3, etc. I could convert the data into a Table if that helps.

Comment: How are the R1, R2... names formed? Are they always in the form of Rx where x is a number? Does R change? Are your numbers limited to 1 digit?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose The names R1, R2 etc are simple text (no forumula). They are always "R" followed by a single digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array formula:

```
=SUM((COLUMN(B1:D1)-1=G1)*(B1:D9="Y"))
```

Enter this formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. Where:

B1:D1 represent the "R" columns headers.
B1:D9 represent the "R" columns data.
G1 represents the Round to look up.

This formula essentially creates an array of 1s wherever there is a "Y", but multiplies it by 1 if the column matches your lookup or 0 if it doesn't. Those items multiplied by 0 are effectively suppressed and you're left with only those that match both the "Y" flag and the correct column number.

The benefit to using this method is it's very easy to expand and, assuming the names in column A will never be "Y", can even be implemented in a table structure to automatically expand with the formula as:

```
=SUM((COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])-1=G1)*(Table1="Y"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found an alternative way of calculating the number. It uses a feature of the `INDEX` function (which is not volatile) that I had missed. If you enter 0 for the row argument and something (let's call it `col`) as the column argument, `INDEX` will return the entire `col` column as an array. The column array can then be searched by `COUNTIF`

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($B:$D,0,G1),"Y")
```

[image]

Of course you can also enter 0 for the column instead of the row to get `INDEX` to return  an entire row as an array.

Answer (score 0):

*This non volatile formula will help you to get rid from the issue.*

```
=COUNTIF(CHOOSE($G$2,$B$2:$B$10,$C$2:$C$10,$D$2:$D$10),"Y")
```

**Note:**

- To avoid Cell references you may use `Named/Dynamic Named Range` in the formula.
- Adjust the cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: This works but gets messy if the number of columns of data is more than 3. For that reason, I decided to accept the answer from Nayrb.

Comment: @Blackwood, no issue it's true that #Nayrb's formula is quite intelligent. ☺